# htaccess redirect domain to wordpress page?

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have a domain page http://www.domain.com or domain.com

and I would like to use htaccess to redirect http://www.domain.com or domain.com to domain.wordpress.com

I currently have this:

```
RewriteOptions inherit
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/domain\.wordpress\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```

It is not redirecting, can someone assist me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on

Options -Indexes

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/domain\.wordpress\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```

it works for me.. hope this helps